# video autoplay not working on safari iOS 15.5

Tags: javascript, html, css

so, I have this code:

```
 <video id="video-collection" loop playsinline autoplay muted data-desktop-vid="./img/yearcolor-page/section_first-video.mp4" data-mobile-vid="./img/yearcolor-page/video.mp4"></video>
```

as you can see autoplay and muted attributes are set, but on Safari iOS 15.5 video still doesn't autoplay and [has this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq4BB.jpg). I also tested it on iOS 14.8 and all works fine. any idea how can I fix it on iOS 15.5?

**update**
The problem was in low power mode. now I have another question: Is it even possible to force video autoplay with low power mode on?
if not I need at least make a play button which Safari adds work, because now it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is it definitely v15.5 that is the problem? Have  you checked that there isn't a low power mode setting and/or is the video very large? Can you insert a runnable snippet into your question which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @AHaworth yeah, it seems problem was in low power mode. didn't know about that, thanks. but isn't there any way to make it work with low power mode on? or at least make play button which safari adds work, because now it doesn't.

Comment: any document from apple for this low power mode?